# How reset to default zoom/scale a plot type contour created with React-plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using React-Plotly to display a contour graph like this:

```
  <Plot
          data={surfacesData}
          layout={layout}
          // Id to be used by Plotly methods (download,relayout....)
          divId={"surfaces_container"}
          config={{ displayModeBar: false }}
 />
```

[Layout definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqDho.png)

When i tried to call Plotly.relayout in this plot (type contour) using the following code:

```
 Plotly.relayout("surfaces_container", {
        "scene.xaxis.autorange":true,
        "scene.yaxis.autorange":true
      });
```

The following error appears:

"plotly.min.js:107179 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_inputDomain')"

[error][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibZnq.png

How could i reset scale ? i also tried to change xaxis.range instead of scene.xaxis.range... But still not working, and i dont want to force a reset like passing new autorange value as prop.

Plotly.relayout works when i try to change camera position in plot type mesh3d like.

```
Plotly.relayout("surfaces_container", {
        camera :{
          up:{x:0, y:0, z:1},
          center:{x:0, y:0, z:0},
          eye:{x:1.25, y:1.25, z:1.25}
      }});
```

Thank you :)